# growth and decay finding t formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The amount of fish in the main pool increases every month by 5%. Today, we have 6 tonnes of fish in the pool.

In how many years will there be 6.6 tonnes of fish in the pool?

So I can solve it like this:

```
mt = 6.6
m0 = 6
q = 1 + 5/100 = 1.05
t = ?
```

6.6 = 6 * 1.05 ^ t

```
6.6 / 6 = 1.1

1.1 = 1.05^1 (Nope).
1.1 = 1.05^2 = 1.1025 (Most close)
```

So the answer to the question is:

2 years, `t = 2`

My question is, is there a formula to do that instead of checking every single time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) to solve that equation for $t$:

$$6.6 = 6(1.05)^t \implies 1.1=1.05^t$$

Now, taking the logarithm of both sides gives you 
$$\log 1.1=\log 1.05^t \implies t = \frac{\log 1.1}{\log 1.05} \approx 1.953$$

The last step makes use of the fact that $\log b^a = a \log b$.

---

**Addition**

The steps in more detail:

First, simplify the equation by dividing both sides by $6$:

$$6.6 = 6 \times 1.05^t \implies 1.1=1.05^t$$

Then take the logarithm of both sides:

$$\log 1.1=\log 1.05^t$$

Now use the fact that the exponent can be moved outside the log expression, i.e. the rule $\log b^a = a \log b$:

$$\log 1.1=t \log 1.05$$

Now divide both sides by $\log 1.05$ to get

$$t = \frac{\log 1.1}{\log 1.05}$$

Comment: I don't understand one thing, what am I supoposed to do that the answer after diving log 1.1 by c?

Comment: @Roy I added more details in the answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes I understand that part, but I am not sure why is the answer 1.953 and not 1.1025 like in my example.

Comment: oh does that mean 2 years? cause 1.953 is closer to 2.0

Comment: @Roy Yes, $1.953 \approx 2$ years.

Comment: That's easy, I am not sure why doesn't our teacher teach that.. she said it's too confusing and the office is not allowing teachers to teach it, as the method is banned from the exams.